# TypeError When using pvfactors_timeseries in pvlib v0.7.1 with pvfactors v.1.5.0

Tags: pvlib

I get the following error (for pvlib v0.7.1 and pvfactors v1.5.0) when using pvfactors_timeseries

```
TypeError: build() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pvarray'
```

for this sample code from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031410/pvlib-bifacial-pvfactors-timeseries-valueerror-buffer-has-wrong-number-of-d):

```
import pandas as pd
from pvlib.bifacial import (pvfactors_timeseries)   
times = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', closed='left', freq='1min',tz=None)
rear_rad = pvfactors_timeseries(
    solar_azimuth=pd.Series(235.7, times),
    solar_zenith=pd.Series(75.6, times),
    surface_azimuth=pd.Series(270.0, times), #cte
    surface_tilt=pd.Series(-72.8, times), #tracker
    axis_azimuth=180.0, #cte
    timestamps=times,
    dni=pd.Series(29.0, times),
    dhi=pd.Series(275.0, times),
    gcr=0.2,
    pvrow_height=2.0,
    pvrow_width=2.0,
    albedo=0.2, #variable mensual
    n_pvrows=3,
    index_observed_pvrow=1,
    rho_front_pvrow=0.03, #reflectividad
    rho_back_pvrow=0.05, #refletividad
    horizon_band_angle=15.0,
    run_parallel_calculations=False
 )
```

I tried editing line 265 in engine.py from-

```
report = None if fn_build_report is None else fn_build_report.build(pvarray)
```

to

```
report = None if fn_build_report is None else fn_build_report.build(report = None, pvarray = pvarray)
```

But then I run into another error in bifacial.py on line 166 (`pvrow = pvarray.pvrows[1] # use center pvrow`):

```
AttributeError: 'OrderedPVArray' object has no attribute 'pvrows'
```

I want to know if any of these problems were addressed in versions of pvlib > 0.7.1 or pvfactors > 1.5.0.
I am not updating pvlib and pvfactors due to codebase refactoring constraints.

P.S- Running the same code with `run_parallel_calculations=True` (which is the default) runs indefinitely (> 20mins) with this warning-

```
ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 56
```

Comment: Hi @Praneeth, I'm not positive what the problem is, but I suggest installing the latest versions of pvlib and pvfactors and seeing if it goes away.  There's no guarantee that an older pvlib (0.7.1 is a couple years old) will work seamlessly with a newer version of pvfactors.

Comment: Hi @kevinsa5, Thanks for the response. I updated to the latest versions of pvlib (to 0.9.1) and pvfactors (1.5.2). pvfactors_timeseries() runs but gives negative total_inc_back along with some zero-divide RunTimeWarnings. Example- 

python3.8/site-packages/pvfactors/geometry/pvground.py:121: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide 
dx = (y1s_pvrow - y_ground) / np.tan(rotation_vec)

python3.8/site-packages/pvfactors/viewfactors/vfmethods.py:181: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
 vf_pvrow_to_gnd_surf * pvrow_surf_length / gnd_surf_length, 0.)

Comment: The runtime warnings are probably safe to ignore. Does the negative output irradiance correspond to negative input irradiance?  If not, please open a new question with a full code (including input data) to reproduce the negative values.

Comment: I think I figured out the reason for negative back irradiance. The aspect ratio I was giving for pvrow_height/pvrow_width was absurd (1/10). 
I think this was leading to the module "running into the ground" giving absurd irradiance values. 
I found that an ideal ratio of approximately 0.5 works well (this may depend on the max_angle).
Thanks for the help!

Comment: FYI I have opened a github issue about "going underground": https://github.com/SunPower/pvfactors/issues/141